# Test if a good query is being issued

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

It is quite usual to find myself writing unit tests against database calls and I always hit the same issue: *How to validate if a good query is being sent to the database?*

Example, I have this class that will send a final update to the database in the following form:

```
update credential set password_hash = ?, password_crypt = ?, password_plain = ? where id = ?
```

(this is a password migration tool, please dont mind the security issues with the `password_plain` field)

Writing the test class for this class, I have mocked the database access class (in this case I am using Spring JDBCTemplate) and captured the issued sql. After I have the sql, I do the following checks:

```
String space = "\\s+";
String optSpace = "\\s*";
String something = ".+";
String optSomething = ".*";

sql = sql.toLowerCase();
assertTrue(sql.matches(optSpace + "update" + space + "credential" + space + "set" + space + something));
assertTrue(sql.matches(something + space + "set" + space + optSomething + "password_hash" + optSpace + "=" + optSpace + "\\?" + something + "where" + something));
assertTrue(sql.matches(something + space + "set" + space + optSomething + "password_crypt" + optSpace + "=" + optSpace + "\\?" + something + "where" + something));
assertTrue(sql.matches(something + space + "set" + space + optSomething + "password_plain" + optSpace + "=" + optSpace + "\\?" + something + "where" + something));
assertTrue(sql.matches(something + space + "where" + space + optSomething + "id" + optSpace + "=" + optSpace + "\\?" + optSomething));
```

With those checks I am indeed validating if the issued SQL contains the most important parts of the update like:

- correct table is being updated
- all the 3 fields are being updated to values passed as parameters
- the `id` is being used in the `where` statement, with its value as a parameter

I could simply validate if the issued query is exactly the expected query above, but that would make the test too restrict for future changes and would force a failure if any part of the query was changed, even if the update stays correct. As I think that tests are written to be used mostly in the future (when you are changing software and need more reassurance for that) and not in the present, this option would make the test kinda useless.

Well, finally, I declare my question: Which better options do we have for validating the issued SQL?

I see a lot of projects that create small embedded databases with a small amount of data for testing classes that deal with the database, but I wanted to write a more *pure* unit test alternative (if I can call that)

Comment: Surely syntactical validity is not the only criterion?  You need to confirm that the query is, in fact, one that will return you the results you need.

Comment: I agree. In this case, im worried about only an update, so the results (amount of rows updated) are not needed to be validated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a good alternative to testing against a real database (even if it's embedded etc). At the moment you're testing that your SQL is syntactically valid, but will it actually *work*. e.g. do you know if it would violate constraints etc...

Mocking etc is all well and good but at some stage you have to test against the database.  I would ensure that where possible you don't test against the database, and then bite the bullet and construct tests around a small database (with suitable rollback/rebuilds etc) to actually confirm correct db functionality.

Comment: I understand. I will probably try to avoid as much database data on my tests but on the integration parts in thinking about using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/intro.html) for that. As my update and select statements are ANSI (running against a PostgreSQL database), i can use an embedded [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) for that

Answer (score 1):

I'd implore you to reconsider the benefits of these tests because

- it is verifying implementation not behavior
- when you change the SQL query in the future (or someone just adds a innocuous space by mistake), you'd have a failing test even if you have preserved behavior.

For the final DataAccessLayer, I'd recommend writing an integration test. One that runs against a real but minimal DB. Sure these tests would be slow but the confidence that they offer is worth it.

So write tests against GetCustomers() and verify the returned DTO contains the right data vs verifying that the SQL query you issued is X.

Comment: Please, check the whole question as the second point that you stated does not apply entirely. About the first point (implementation not behavior), I have to disagree: The ultimate goal of this class is make output to the database and my question is to discuss proper ways to check this output. I see that your suggestion is upgrading the unit test to an integration test using a real database. As this class represents a database integration, thats probably one of the best approaches

Answer (score 1):

don't assert your sql. it's pointless. you will end up comparing passed sql string to another string (also created by you so there is no validation) or you'll have to implement your own database. instead just use existing one. check is query returned correct data or correctly changed data in database. use dbunit or sth similar.